# Is CBC 128bit encryption vulnerable if I expose a start-of-text pattern?

Tags: python, cryptography, sha256, cbc-mode, pycryptodome

I'm doing encryption with my program, but I'm worried about exposing an initial layout in the plaintext.

As you can see, I intend to encrypt sha256 of the plain text plus the plain text, all together, I will use the sha256 to calculate integrity and check if the content was not changed.

encrypt: sha256 of plaintext + plaintext, padding

And as you can see, I'm concerned that an attacker might know that the first few bytes are a pattern of letters and numbers that are part of a sha256 of the original message.

In this case, the IV is not secret, and the attacker could have the IV and the Encryption.

My question is if my method of use is safe or an attacker could get lucky.

An example:

```
#need: pip install pycryptodome

from Crypto.Cipher import AES;
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad;
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes;
from hashlib import sha256;


textPlain = input("Enter text plain: ").encode(); #(secret)
shaMsg = sha256(textPlain).hexdigest();

password = pad(b"APasswordExample", 16, "iso7816"); #(secret)

iv = get_random_bytes(16); #(no secret)

secretBytes = shaMsg.encode()+textPlain;
secretBytes = pad(secretBytes, 16, "iso7816");

cip = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv);
encrypted = cip.encrypt(secretBytes);
```

So I would like you to give me your opinion about my encryption

Thanks :D

Comment: The IV does not have to be kept secret. It is often prepended to the cyphertext, so it is known to any attacker. The important thing is that the IV is not reused for separate messages using the same key. The attacker knowing part of the plaintext is a Known Plaintext Attack, and modern ciphers, such as AES, are secure against such an attack.

Comment: Another way to think about the IV is that any encrypted block (when there are many) is the IV of the next block in CBC. It is safe to transfer as is. Your code uses a random IV, which is good, but it does not add it to the ciphertext, making it impossible to decrypt. Be sure to send/store `iv+encrypted`.

Comment: @rossum ooh! I feel better now.
I'm very curious about what you said about not reusing the iv and the same key, I also like to understand it.

I'm just thinking that maybe it's good to also encrypt the hash and then add it, so it's unformatted.

encrypt all: <encrypt shaMsg> + <msg>, <padding>

can you give me your opinion?

I just don't know if every time the size of the encryption will be the same for the hash

Comment: @ixe013 Of course, only that the iv is not secret, and neither is the method, it is open source and my program will generate many files like this, I hope none of them are vulnerable.

Comment: If you reuse an IV with the same key for different messages, then the attacker can compare the two cyphertexts and get information about various similarities between the files. Basically don't repeat an IV/key combination.